# Linking ODP back to NSF -

Tags: git, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

After some instabilities in Domino Designer (Design elements not showing up), I now have the problem that my NSF can't find its ODP anymore.

When I do right-click/Team Development/Associate with existing On-Disk Project, I get this list which does not include my project.

[image: My on-disk project is not shown]

The ODP is stored outside the default position so that I could set up SourceTree:

[image]

It seems to me that Designer has forgotten its list of ODPs. It's not visible in the Package Explorer list.

I am using IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1FP1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to import the git-nsf as ODP. Call from package explorer with right click "Import..." and choose "General / Existing Projects into Workspace".

After ODP is imported you can assign it to nsf.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks Knut!

Comment: One key is to make sure "Copy Projects into Workspace" isn't ticked (it's not by default). Otherwise it will create a copy of the source control ODP instead of linking to it.

Comment: note to myself: Do the 'Import...' workaround *even if you see the project listed in the package manager*